# Laravel Render external url as route content

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5

Let's say I am an "advertisings distributor" and I have in my web site a **route** located at `/my_ads/{brand}` which name parameter is corresponding to one my of customers brand name such as **Asus** or **Toyota**.

If I want the route `my_ads/asus` to display the content of **external URL** like *"https://www.asus.com"*, how can I do?

In pure **PHP**, [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) would be a solution but is there a proper way of doing so in Laravel?

Comment: You're basically building a proxy. This generally winds up being a lot more work than it initially seems, given issues with cookies, AJAX calls, relative vs. absolute URLs, etc. You can certainly use cURL within Laravel.

Comment: You should use an iframe , that way you also give the 3rd parties control over what you can and can't embed in your page, which is how it should be.

Comment: Yeahh! reat idea. I finally did as you said @apokryfos . Using [Iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) was my last card because. I' ve noticed a quite problem with CURL.